# Add sources to sbt assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am using sbt assembly to create a library, for internal purposes.

I am publishing this jar to a local artifactory installation, and it works nicely.

However, I still haven't figured out how to add the source code to the assembly creation process, so when I import it in intellij it will also be available (for debugging, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

As I understand when you do assembly it will look all jars,source etc in `cache directory` i.e `/$HOME/.ivy2/cache/` `if your name-version-source.jar is available in cache then in your final assembled jar will have source.jar`

```
In your case you publishing it as local so your source,javadoc jars are generated in local directory i.e /$HOME/.ivy2/local/
```

So here you go `publish the jar to central repository not as publishLocal` or as `hack In your /$HOME/.ivy2/local/artifact-id/group-id/version/ directory  docs,jars,ivys,pom,srcs copy those directory to /$HOME/.ivy2/cache/artifact-id/ paste it here` 
Then try assembly in my case works for me

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you are telling me to do.